# find specific text in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a specific piece of text i'm trying to get using BeautifulSoup and Python, however I am not sure how to get it using sou.find().

I am trying to obtain "#1 in Beauty" only from the following.

```
<ul>
<li>...<li>
<li>...<li>
<li id="salesRank">
    <b>Amazon Best Sellers Rank:</b>
    "#1 in Beauty ("
    <a href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/beauty/ref=pd_dp_ts_k_1"> See top 100</a>
    ")
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [find_all](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/python-on-the-web/beautifulsoup-4-python/) method of `soup`. Try below

```
import urllib, urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
url='your url here'
content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
print soup.find_all('#1 in Beauty')
```